# Python networkx: node are not taking color list

Tags: python, networkx

I started learning Python to use networkx. I am trying to build a hierarchy rooted at some node (node 0), and I want the colors to change according to distance (in hops) from that node. I have written the following code, but I don't know why the colors are not changing!! can you please point out the problem?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import random

# initial values of rings in nodes
MAX_RING = 1000

class Node:
    count = int(0)
    tx_range = 3
    def __init__(self, i):
        Node.count+= 1
        self.id = int(i)
        self.ring = int(MAX_RING)
        self.x_pos = int()
        self.y_pos = int()
        self.parent_list = list()
        self.nbr_list = list()
        self.color = float()


    def addNbr(self, nbr):
        self.nbr_list.append(nbr)

def createNodes(Nodes, pos, labels):
    for i in range(num_of_nodes):
        Nodes.append(Node(i))
        Nodes[i].x_pos = random.randrange(net_width)
        Nodes[i].y_pos = random.randrange(net_hieght)
        pos[i] = (Nodes[i].x_pos, Nodes[i].y_pos)
        labels[i] = i


def createEdges(Graph, Nodes, Edges):
    for i in range(num_of_nodes):
        for j in range(i + 1, num_of_nodes):
            dist = ((Nodes[i].x_pos - Nodes[j].x_pos)**2 + (Nodes[i].y_pos - Nodes[j].y_pos)**2) ** 0.5
            if dist <= Node.tx_range:
                Graph.add_edge(i, j)
                #Graph.add_edge(j, i)
                Edges.append((i , j))
                Nodes[i].addNbr(Nodes[j])
                Nodes[j].addNbr(Nodes[i])
                print("Edge added")

def createRings(G, Nodes, colors, VisEdges):
    # Base station is node 0 and has ring 0
    # find all nodes in current ring and check their neighbors to create the next ring
    # next ring becomes current ring and repeat from previous step
    current_ring = 0
    current_node = Nodes[0]
    current_node.ring = current_ring
    # temporary set to travers all nodes initially contains the BS
    N = [Nodes[0]]
    while len(N) > 0:
        node = N.pop(0)
        for nbr in node.nbr_list:
            # for each node check if it has a neighbor with ring less than MAX_RING
            if nbr.ring > node.ring + 1:
                if(nbr.ring != MAX_RING):
                    print('CHANGING PARENT')
                nbr.ring = node.ring + 1
                nbr.color = nbr.ring
                N.append(nbr)
                VisEdges.append((node.id, nbr.id))
    for node in Nodes:
        colors.insert(node.id, node.color)




def main():
    Nodes = list()
    Edges = list()
    VisEdges = list()
    pos = dict()
    labels = {}
    colors = []
    G = nx.Graph()
    createNodes(Nodes, pos, labels)
    G.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
    createEdges(G, Nodes, Edges)
    for n, p in pos.items():
        G.node[n]['pos'] = p

    createRings(G, Nodes, colors, VisEdges)
    colors[0] = 1
    for node in Nodes:
        print('Node[',node.id,'] ring is ', node.ring, 'color is', colors[node.id])


    nx.draw(G,pos, edgelist=VisEdges, nodelist=pos.keys() , node_colors=colors, cmap=cmx.get_cmap('Reds'),
            vmin=0, vmax=max(colors))

    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=10)
    plt.show()



num_of_nodes = 100
net_width = 15
net_hieght = 15
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your argument list to `nx.draw()`.  It should be `node_color`, i.e.

```
nx.draw(G,pos, edgelist=VisEdges, nodelist=pos.keys() , node_color=colors, cmap=cmx.get_cmap('Reds'),
        vmin=0, vmax=max(colors))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent a whole day trying to figure it out and I couldn't see it!! why wasn't it detected by python interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your call to nx.draw(). This typo was not caught by the interpreter since you can pass whatever keyword arguments you want to the function, its just that certain keywords get acted on/are of use.